# Connecting to remote Mapr Hive via JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, hadoop, hive, mapr

This question is similar, but not the same, as [Hive JDBC getConnection does not return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769477/hive-jdbc-getconnection-does-not-return) . Yet this is about a remote connection. Also the metastore is present in the directory in which the hiveserver2 was started.

We have a running mapr cluster on a remote machine. I would like to connect to Hive on this cluster using Java JDBC.

Hence we started the hive server:

/opt/mapr/hive/hive-0.11/bin/hiveserver2

The output of the server process does not contain any error messages. It listens on port 10000 as reported by netstat.

I try to connect to the server as described in https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient, thereby replacing localhost by the server name where the hiveserver2 is running:

```
Connection con = 
  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://myserver.example.com:10000/default", "", "");
```

Yet the program hangs exactly at this statement. It does not seem to get a connection.

Possibly I need to supply a username and password?

Initially I had used the driver org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.

Yet it seems like I should be using the driver org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver if the hive2 server is running. Now I am getting the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://myserver.example.com:10000/default: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:246)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:132)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:105)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:22)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null)
at org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.read(TApplicationException.java:108)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:71)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.recv_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:144)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:131)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:237)
... 10 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to get around it by adding the correct dependency to my pom.xml file.  I was getting the latest apache release of hive from maven central and switched to using the cdh4 release from the cloudera repo.  So, what you are seeing may be a symptom of having the wrong hive-jdbc dependency.  Here's the maven snippet I added to my pom file:

```
<repository>
<id>cloudera</id>
<url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
</repository>
...
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
<artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
<version>0.10.0-cdh4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Here's a link about the [cloudera repo](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_31.html).

Also, adding the ";auth=noSasl" to the URL made my application hang so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like you cannot use the jdbc client from central maven with cloudera.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to specify the username. Also itshould be **hive2** not **hive** since you are using hiveserver2.
Try modifying your connection url:

```
Connection con = 
  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://myserver.example.com:10000/default", "<user>", "");
```

Its given in the link [Hive2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients)

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: thanks. With hive2 it gives the following Exception: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Invalid URL: jdbc:hive2://myserver.example.com:10000/default
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:86)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:106)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
 at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:22)

Comment: seems like I am using the wrong driver: http://grokbase.com/p/cloudera/cdh-user/12bwb8fdbd/hive-jdbc-timeout . Now I am getting the Exception : Required field 'client_protocol' is unset! Struct:TOpenSessionReq(client_protocol:null)

Comment: Try adding this in hive-site.xml :

<property>
     <name>hive.server2.authentification</name>
     <value>NOSASL</value>
   </property>
And append this **;auth=noSasl** in the jdbc url.
Also make sure hiveserver2 is running at port 10000.

Comment: thanks. Now the connection hangs again. Possibly I am using the wrong username. Currently I am using the linux system user that started hive.

Comment: Can you make sure you have System.exit in catch block where you are having
the Hive connection block. This would exit your program if it encounters an
exception otherwise it would take a while to exit. I am not sure this piece is already in your code if is, it would give the right reason exception.

  catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       System.exit(1);
     }

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem.
Please check if server is reachable on the port 10000 from the client (server and port are enabled no firewall is restricting) also check hiveserver is up and running. if yes then it should work.
following code work for me for mapr hive.

if you have any query related mapr, please refer answers.mapr.com, this contain most of the information which you might be requiring.

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


import java.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile.Writer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.*;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
    //private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
    /**
    * @param args
    * @throws SQLException
    **/
    private static Logger mLogger = Logger.getLogger(HiveJdbcClient.class);
    private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        HiveJdbcClient myJob = new HiveJdbcClient();
        myJob.execute();
    }
    public void execute() throws SQLException {
        //mLogger.info("Start HiveJob");
        System.out.println("Start HiveJob");
        try {
            Class.forName(driverName);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://myserver:10000/default", "", "");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "SHOW TABLES";
        //String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
       // ResultSet res1 = stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
        System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (res.next()) {
            System.out.println(res.getString(1));
        }

        //mLogger.info("HiveJob executed!");
        System.out.println("HiveJob executed!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the beeline client to connect to hive using JDBC.

It would be some thing like: beeline !connect jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000

check the link:
http://dwbitechguru.blogspot.ca/2014/11/how-to-connect-to-hadoop-hive-using.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding the: `;auth=noSasl` to the JDBC connect string solved the endless waiting for the connection !

```
jdbc:hive2://server:10000/default;auth=noSasl
```

Answer (score -1):

You should get hive-service-X.XX.X-cdhX.X.X.jar here :https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/org/apache/hive/;
It works fine to me.