# How can I trace the failure ot TSaslTransport (hive related)

Tags: hive, thrift, sasl

I've been debugging a JDBC Connection error in hive, similar to what was asked here:

[Hive JDBC getConnection does not return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769477/hive-jdbc-getconnection-does-not-return/22887272).

By turning on log4j properly, i finally got down to seeing this , before the getConnection() hangs.  What is thrift waiting for ? If this is related to using the wrong thrift APIs, how can I determine versioning differences between client/server?

I have tried copying all libraries from my hive server onto my client app to test if it is some kind of minor thrift class versioning error, but that didnt solve the problem, my JDBC connection still hangs.

`0    [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - opening transport org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport@219ba640
0 [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - opening transport org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport@219ba640
3    [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport  - Sending mechanism name PLAIN and initial response of length 14
3 [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslClientTransport  - Sending mechanism name PLAIN and initial response of length 14
5    [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: Writing message with status START and payload length 5
5 [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: Writing message with status START and payload length 5
5    [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: Writing message with status COMPLETE and payload length 14
5 [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: Writing message with status COMPLETE and payload length 14
5    [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: Start message handled
5 [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: Start message handled
5    [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: Main negotiation loop complete
5 [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: Main negotiation loop complete
6    [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: SASL Client receiving last message
6 [main] DEBUG org.apache.thrift.transport.TSaslTransport  - CLIENT: SASL Client receiving last message`